# ng-if doesn't prevent URLs in inner HTML from being evaluated

Tags: angularjs

I have some HTML that is conditionalized with the `ng-if` tag.

```
<div ng-if="localVideoExists">
    <video id="videoPlayer" controls src='{{localVideoSrc}}' style="max-height: 400px;" />
</div>
```

At no time does the condition in the `ng-if` directive evaluate as `true`.  I would think that this means the inner HTML would never be added to the `DOM`.  However, my web server logs show many requests in the form

`/{{localVideoSrc}}`

So, something is causing the video tag to pop into existence (although I never find it in the `DOM`) and it is creating a web request based on the not-yet-evaluated Angular template string `{{localVideoSrc}}`.  I cannot seem to prevent this behavior. In fact, the first line in my controller is:

```
$scope.localVideoExists = false;
```

I've also disabled any functionality for now, that would ever set `localVideoExists` to `true`.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of that is that Angular loads after the `DOM` has loaded. So the HTML is parsed and **executed** before Angular is activated. So, the browser loads the HTML inside the `ng-if` body and makes a request for the `{{localVideoSrc}}`.

To prevent this kind of behavior, use `ng-src`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Probably, you also need to use the [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service because of security.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-src` instead `src`

```
<div ng-if="localVideoExists">
    <video id="videoPlayer" controls ng-src='{{localVideoSrc}}' style="max-height: 400px;" />
</div>
```

please see more here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: Oh, brother - that was silly of me.  For some reason I had thought that ng-src just applied to the <img> tag.  Thank you!